# Testing functions inside controllers in angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test whether or not a particular function was called in my Angular controller.

```
.controller('demo',function(){

  function init(){
     //some code..
  }

  init();
}
```

My test code looks something like below:

```
describe(..

  beforeEach(...
   function createController() { /*call this fn to create controller */
   )

  describe('controller initilization'.function(){
     var spy = spyOn(this,init)
     createController();  
     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
   }

)
```

ofcourse the above unit test fails. So how would i check if the function init() was called ?

Comment: you can't, you need to make the init function public so it can be tested

Comment: so i should define it as scope.init ?

Comment: There should be no `$scope` when testing, unless you are writing E2E tests...

Comment: you can do either $scope or just this.init

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921602/angularjs-prevent-init-method-on-controller-from-launching-during-jasmine-tests

Comment: this.init doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote isnt "spy-able".
So either dont spy on init or only mock the controller collaborators.

You wrote the equivalent of a private method in Java.So make it public OR make the method belong to a collaborator.

move init into a service,pass the $scope as an argument if needed.

```
module.service('Init',function(){
    this.init=function($scope){};
})
.controller('Ctrl',function($scope,Init){
       Init.init($scope);
})
```

then

```
$scope=$rootScope.new();
Init=$injector.get('Init');
spyOn(Init,'init');
Ctrl=$controller('Ctrl',{$scope:$scope});


expect(Init.init).toHaveBeenCalledWith($scope);
```